# boost::filesystem::wpath on Android

Tags: android, c++, boost

`boost::filesystem` provides many interesting functions, for example, we can use `boost::filesystem::exists` to check whether one file exists or not. I am now using this functionality in Android. It succeeds in the following program:

```
int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    string file_name="/data/local/tmp/abc/def.txt";
    boost::filesystem::path dddddd(file_name);
    if(boost::filesystem.exists(dddddd))
    {
        std::cout<<"Succeed"<<std::endl;

     }
    else
    {
        std::cout<<"Failed"<<std::endl;
     }
    return 0;

}
```

However, if I use wstring instead:

```
 int main()
    {
        using namespace std;
        wstring file_name=L"/data/local/tmp/abc/def.txt";
        boost::filesystem::wpath dddddd(file_name);
        if(boost::filesystem.exists(dddddd))
        {
            std::cout<<"Succeed"<<std::endl;

         }
        else
        {
            std::cout<<"Failed"<<std::endl;
         }
        return 0;

    }
```

It will fail. It seems to me that the reason is because Android does not handle `wstring` very well. Any idea how I can change in order to make sure `boost::filesystem::wpath` can work on Android?

Comment: Why would you even want to use `std::wstring`? You aren't on Windows.

Comment: @sjdowling Thanks for your comments, and it is a Windows program, and I am porting it to Android.

Comment: In my version of boost 1.57 `wpath` is just a typedef for `path` which uses `wchar_t` when compiling on Windows. 
I think you should really reconsider the costs of trying to use `wstring` on Linux as there are so many complications involved. For instance `wchar_t` is 16 bits on Windows and 32 bits on Linux. You say you are writing for Android in which case you cannot assume little endian architecture which lots of software using UTF-16 does. Glibc doesn't provide `_wfopen` functions and so on.